# Reverse proxy a Wordpress multi-site under a folder in another Wordpress multi-site

Tags: wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy, multisite, proxypass

We have 2 Wordpress multisite installations in 2 different servers and we are trying to have the testing environment accessed as a subfolder under the production environment. So if the production site is [www.production.com](http://www.production.com), we want the testing site to be [www.production.com/testing](http://www.production.com/testing).

We have looked at countless example to accomplish this, and we have made some progress, but the main difference is that we have a multisite on top of another multisite.

We have configured the servers as it is shown below and we got the main page for testing site to display under [www.production.com/testing](http://www.production.com/testing), we also got a sub-site to load under [www.produciton.com/testing/subsite1/](http://www.produciton.com/testing/subsite1/). Here are the issues. When we go to [www.production.com/testing/wp-admin/](http://www.production.com/testing/wp-admin/), we end up with [www.production.com/wp-login.php?return_url=xx..](http://www.production.com/wp-login.php?return_url=xx..). If we add testing to this url [www.production.com/testing/wp-login.php?return_url=xx.](http://www.production.com/testing/wp-login.php?return_url=xx.). , URL does not change but we can see that the login page came from production.com.

Also it appears the main content of pages in sub-sites is correct but all the images and styles seem to be coming from the production site.

Here is where we are so far.

**Production Server**

We’ve put in following changes to the nginx Production.conf under sites-enabled:

```
rewrite ^/testing/(.*)$ /$1 break;

proxy_pass https://www.testing.com/;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

}

if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite /testing/wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
rewrite ^/testing (/wp-((?!json).)*)$ /testing$1 last;
rewrite ^/testing (/.*\.php.*)$ /testing$1 last;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-((?!json).)*)$ $1 last;
rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}

location @prod_serv {

if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite "^/ testing /wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" "https://www.testing.com/wp-content/uploads/$1" redirect;
rewrite "^/ testing /(.*)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" "https://www.testing.com/wp-content/uploads/$2" redirect;
rewrite "^(.*)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$" "https://www.production.com/wp-content/uploads/$2" redirect;
}
}
```

**Testing server**

No changes to the nginx configuration file on testing side.
Following are tables updated in the testing side.

**wp_options table**

```
option Name |  Option Value
--------------------------------------------
Siteurl       | (ProductionDomain)/testing
home          | (TestingDomain)
```

**Wp_4_options**

```
Option_id | Option name | Option value
------------------------------------------------
1         | siteurl     |(ProductionDomain)/testing/subsite1
2         | home        |(TestingDomain)/subsite1
```

Any advice from anyone would be greatly appreciated.